# Identity Core Primary Key as Int not able to use SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Setup login/logout using Identity Core, with the Primary Key as Int. I followed the following article in the ASP.NET Core Documentation: [Configure Identity primary keys data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration). (They use GUID's but the idea is the same).
The setup is quite succesfull, the ID's are integers and the database is getting populated.

However, when I try to sign in using the built-in `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` and invoking the the method

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Username,Password, RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

I'm sure the SecurityTimeStamp is filled up and the services are added in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My classes:

ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

ApplicationRole

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
    }
```

Stacktrace

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value
>      at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType, String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey, String propertyValue)
>      at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2.<CreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.<SignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__46.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__33.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Controllers.AccountController.<Login>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\src\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 64
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: did you forget step 3 change or only in the question?

Comment: Only in the question SO question, i've added it so there is no confusion. Thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropped and recreated the database ... pretty obvious.

//Solved.

Answer (score 0):

3 years later I have stubmled upon this issue. Recreating database didn't help. I have changed as above the `PK` from `string` to `int` and `UserManager` have been creating records successfully but then the `SignInManager` have been failing to sign in the newly created user with the same error.

Solution:

I have found out that just assiging a role to the user upon creation solved the issue.

```
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Basic.ToString());
```