# UserManager Keeps throwing a System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to implemented the standard `Id` in `AspNetUsers` from `nvarchar` to `int`. I've manage to get that side working. However my issue is when I try to login I keep getting an error from the `UserManager` class.

My code is below:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public UserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store) 
    : base(store) 
{ 
}
```

And on the login page I've got

```
if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
            var user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text); //This line throws the error
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");                }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

The error I keep getting is **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: manager**. Has anyone else come across this issue? Thanks in advance for your help

**Stack Trace**

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: manager]
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Find(UserManager`2 manager, String userName, String password) +221
Account_Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Login.aspx.cs:17
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628026
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +5226
```

Comment: Could you specify which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @MotiAzu for me it's this line `var user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);`

Comment: @Izzy paste the full stack trace of your `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5 (VS2012) Identity CreateIdentityAsync - Value cannot be null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918000/mvc5-vs2012-identity-createidentityasync-value-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that `UserManager` is registered in you OWIN context. You should have something like this in your `Startup` class:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Also ensure that you have `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]` attribute applied to your web assembly.

Comment: After trying your suggestion, I get the same error but on `public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)` line :/

Comment: @Izzy which means the solution is correct and you're just encountering some other problem, which might be hard to help you with, as you haven't provided any code surrounding that line.

Comment: @Izzy - I'd use your best judgment to either provide that code, or ask a separate question if it's not related (it doesn't seem to be at first glance - the bit you've provided doesn't mention your `manager` instance).

Comment: @Izzy maybe your `ApplicationDbContext` is not registered in OWIN too? Check the same thing I suggested in the answer for `ApplicationDbContext` as well.

Comment: @Sergey Just checked my `ApplicationDbContext` is registered

Answer (score 2):

the manager.Find() method only search in primary key of table, you must use something like :

```
Context db = new Context();
if (db.Users.Select(u => u).Where(u => u.Username == Username && u.Pass == Password).ToList().Count() == 1)
{
      // login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the very basic of setups.  Can you check that you're user manager is registered in your **OWIN** context.
And In any case you've extended the Identity **ApplicationUser** attributes, please do ensure that you've made them public and  that they have getters and setters.