# Identity error: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I using ASP.NET Identity and when a user want to register get this error:

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: manager.

Here is my Register Action code:

```
public virtual ActionResult Register(string nm, string em, string ps)
    {
        var redirectUrlPanel = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "HomeUsers", new { area = "Users" });
        var redirectUrlAuction = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Auction", "Default", new { area = "" });

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = new Q_Users();
                user.UserName = nm;
                user.Email = em;
                user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                var adminresult = UserManager.Create(user, ps);

                //Add User Admin to Role Admin
                if (adminresult.Succeeded)
                {
                    //Find Role Admin
                    var role = RoleManager.FindByName("Admin");
                    var result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return Json(new { OK = "1", UrlPanel = redirectUrlPanel, UrlAuction = redirectUrlAuction });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { OK = "0", UrlPanel = redirectUrlPanel, UrlAuction = redirectUrlAuction });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            return Json(new { OK = "0", UrlPanel = redirectUrlPanel, UrlAuction = redirectUrlAuction });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { OK = "0", UrlPanel = redirectUrlPanel, UrlAuction = redirectUrlAuction });
        }
    }
```

And the error in this Line: `var adminresult = UserManager.Create(user, ps);`

Comment: No UserManager is not null. Yeah I not doing anything with 'ex' but know the error message! Is the SecurityStamp OK? I don't know what is Parameter name manager

Comment: inner exception is empty

Comment: Check the 'ex' inner exception and call stack... or add another catch(ArgumentNullException e) and check StackTrace

Comment: read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060662/usermanager-keeps-throwing-a-system-argumentnullexception AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918000/mvc5-vs2012-identity-createidentityasync-value-cannot-be-null

Comment: Inner Exception in second catch is null too and StackTrace is this: StackTrace = "at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Create[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, TUser user, String password)\r\n   at Diaxin.Controllers.DefaultController.Register(String nm, String us, String ps) in "Controller Path":line 213"

Comment: Ok, check 1st link for OWIN or 2nd for SecurityStamp

Comment: I did all of that but the error is still Alive :| :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the role manager was not initialized

To resolve this, follow the steps below

1. In the `IdentityModels.cs` file of the `Models` folder, Add the class below to the `Models` `namespace`.

   ```
     public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
     {
           public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
           public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }

     }
   ```
2. In you `IdentityConfig.cs` file in `App_Start` folder, Add the class below

   ```
   public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
   {
       public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
           : base(roleStore)
       {
       }

       public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
       {
           return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Go to `Startup.Auth.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder and add the code below to the `ConfigureAuth` Method.

   ```
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
   ```

You should stop getting the errors after this.

Hope this helps.